# is it better to delay executing FB messenger js code using setTimeOut() to not block page rendering

Tags: javascript, wordpress, settimeout, facebook-messenger

when trying to analyse my page speed using Google page speed analytics.

I see that FB messenger load a lot of js files.

so, I decided to delay FB script using setTimeOut() method.

```
<!-- Load Facebook SDK for JavaScript -->
      <div id="fb-root"></div>
      <script defer>

          jQuery(window).load(function(){
               function load_fb_chat(){

                window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
                  FB.init({
                    appId            : 'myappid',
                    autoLogAppEvents : true,
                    xfbml            : true,
                    version          : 'v7.0'
                  });
                };

                (function(d, s, id) {
                var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
                if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
                js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
                js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk/xfbml.customerchat.js';
                fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
              }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

               };
               window.setTimeout( load_fb_chat, 2000 ); //or 500ms
            })
</script>
```

but I am not sure if it's a good practice.